# Jenkins console output format for selemium webdriver execution

Tags: selenium, logging, jenkins, selenium-webdriver, console-output

I am executing selenium webdriver scripts through jenkins and logging some info through logger.info. On console output of jenkins it is showing as [testng] 2014-10-28 23:52:29,868 (pool-1-thread-2). I am not able to figure it out what "868" is referring to?

I looked at line no in source code but no it is not the same so it is something different.

Answer (score 0):

That should be the milliseconds of the time.

Answer (score 0):

That appears to be a poorly formatted time field and should be a dot rather than a comma to denote milliseconds. The ISO8601 DateTime Standard would be more like `HH:mm:ss.SSS` (or `yyyy-DDD'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS` in full)